# REST api responses

Tags: c#, rest, model-view-controller

Given this code, the entry for a C# REST API,

```
protected HttpResponseMessage ProcessRequest()
{
    HttpResponseMessage _response = null;
    try
    {
        //request is processed.
        object _obj = ExecuteEvent();

        //response object is created with success status and response content is assigned in the required mediatype format.
        _response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Constants.ServiceConstants.VALUE);
        _response.Content = new StringContent(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(_obj), Encoding.UTF8, Constants.ServiceConstants.MEDIATYPE);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return _response;
}
```

Returning a 200 response for every request and just setting the content to the serialized JSON as above, is this the right or wrong way to go about this?

I would have thought that we definitely should not just be returning a 200 OK for every request.

This code will throw an exception in `ExecuteEvent`, let's say if the user is unauthorized, however, shouldn't we actually be telling the caller that their request is unauthorized?

Answer (score 0):

You should send back an HTTP status based ok what happened in your method.  If everything worked correctly, you send back an OK.  If there is a failure, you should send back the appropriate status code.

For example, if ExecuteEvent throws a message indicating that the user is not authorized, you would send back an HTTP stays code of Forbidden (a 403).

You can see all of Microsft's status codes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx) and you can get a list of the numbers and what they mean [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).  Most of the time these two lists with correspond to each other, they are just organized a little differently.

Hope that helps.